# Warning illegal string offset on line 240

Tags: php

I have installed an wp theme and while I open an plugin I got that error illegal string offset on line 240.

This is line 240:

```
echo '<option value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option['name'], '</option>';
```

Pls Help

Comment: Check value of `$option`

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet expects `$option` variable to be an array, but for some reason in the code preceding this line, it is probably accidentally set to a string value.

Tip: Look out for variable reuse - same variable being used for different purposes.

Adding a `var_dump($option);` before this line and checking output is one way to start debugging the issue.